# How to create balanced k-means geospatial clusters?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, geospatial

I have 9000 USA-based points (that are accounts) with a variety of different string and numeric columns/attributes. I'm trying to evenly divide these points/accounts up into equitable groupings that are both spatially grouped as well as weighted (in a gravity sense) by number of employees, which is one of the columns/attributes. I used sklearn K-means clustering to do a grouping and it seemed to work fine but I noticed that the groupings are not equal. Some of the groups have ~600 and some of them have ~70. This is somewhat logical as there is more data in certain areas. The problem here is that I need these groups to be more equal. Here’s the code I used:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 30, max_iter=1000, init ='k-means++')

lat_long = dftobeclustered[dftobeclustered.columns[1:3]]
_employees = dftobeclustered[dftobeclustered.columns[3]]

weighted_kmeans_clusters = kmeans.fit(lat_long, sample_weight = _employees)
dftobeclustered['cluster_label'] = kmeans.predict(lat_long, sample_weight = _employees)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_ 

labels = dftobeclustered['cluster_label']
```

Is it possible to divide up the k-means clusters in a more equal way? I think the core problem is that it breaks low population areas like Montana or Hawaii off into their own groups when I actually need it to combine those areas into bigger groups. But I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

K-means is not written to work that way. Observations are assigned to clusters based on their actual MEASURED distances from centroids.

If you try to coerce the the number of members in a cluster, it completely un-does the that distance measurement component, especially when you are talking geographically with Lat Lon.

You may need to look at another method of subsetting your observations or reconsider the equivalent sizes of clusters.

In all honesty, most of the time geographic distance-clustering is directly related to the  similarity of observations in other ways (think of how house styles, or demographics or income in neighborhoods and how that might translate to a zip code or trees types in a localized region). These sorts of things do not respect our needs for them to be groups of the same size.

Clusters based on qualities OTHER than geography are more likely to level out if there is clear differentiation in even numbers of observations than straight up lat lon, as they will be distance sorted...no way around it.

So areas with dense populations of observations WILL have more members than those with less. And the distance between MT and HI will always be greater than MT and NYC so they will NOT be geographically cluster by distance.

I understand that you want equal groupings...is it necessary that they are geographically grouped? Given the fact that MT and HI would be together, the geographic label would not mean much. It might be better to use all of the NON geographic numerical values to cluster to create observations that are contextually alike.

Otherwise, you can use business rules to dissect the observations (by this I mean if var_x > 7 & var_y <227 & .... label=1 and make some groups yourself. You can use `groupby()` and `describe()` in pandas to create cross tables to see what might be good values to split on.

Answer (score 1):

Try DBSCAN.  See my sample code below.

```
# import necessary modules
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, time
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from geopy.distance import great_circle
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint


# define the number of kilometers in one radian
kms_per_radian = 6371.0088


# load the data set
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\summer-travel-gps-full.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df.head()


# how many rows are in this data set?
len(df)


# scatterplot it to get a sense of what it looks like
df = df.sort_values(by=['lat', 'lon'])
ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='lon', y='lat', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0)

 

# represent points consistently as (lat, lon)
# coords = df.as_matrix(columns=['lat', 'lon'])
df_coords = df[['lat', 'lon']]
# coords = df.to_numpy(df_coords)

# define epsilon as 10 kilometers, converted to radians for use by haversine
epsilon = 10 / kms_per_radian


start_time = time.time()
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=10, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(df_coords))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
unique_labels = set(cluster_labels)

# get the number of clusters
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))


# get colors and plot all the points, color-coded by cluster (or gray if not in any cluster, aka noise)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels)))

# for each cluster label and color, plot the cluster's points
for cluster_label, color in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    
    size = 150
    if cluster_label == -1: #make the noise (which is labeled -1) appear as smaller gray points
        color = 'gray'
        size = 30
    
    # plot the points that match the current cluster label
    # X.iloc[:-1]
    # df.iloc[:, 0]
    x_coords = df_coords.iloc[:, 0]
    y_coords = df_coords.iloc[:, 1]
    ax.scatter(x=x_coords, y=y_coords, c=color, edgecolor='k', s=size, alpha=0.5)

ax.set_title('Number of clusters: {}'.format(num_clusters))
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
coefficient = metrics.silhouette_score(df_coords, cluster_labels)
print('Silhouette coefficient: {:0.03f}'.format(metrics.silhouette_score(df_coords, cluster_labels)))


# set eps low (1.5km) so clusters are only formed by very close points
epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_radian

# set min_samples to 1 so we get no noise - every point will be in a cluster even if it's a cluster of 1
start_time = time.time()
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(df_coords))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
unique_labels = set(cluster_labels)

# get the number of clusters
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))

# all done, print the outcome
message = 'Clustered {:,} points down to {:,} clusters, for {:.1f}% compression in {:,.2f} seconds'
print(message.format(len(df), num_clusters, 100*(1 - float(num_clusters) / len(df)), time.time()-start_time))


# Result:
Silhouette coefficient: 0.854
Clustered 1,759 points down to 138 clusters, for 92.2% compression in 0.17 seconds

coefficient = metrics.silhouette_score(df_coords, cluster_labels)
print('Silhouette coefficient: {:0.03f}'.format(metrics.silhouette_score(df_coords, cluster_labels)))



# number of clusters, ignoring noise if present
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels)) #- (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
print('Number of clusters: {}'.format(num_clusters))
```

Result:

```
Number of clusters: 138


# create a series to contain the clusters - each element in the series is the points that compose each cluster
clusters = pd.Series([df_coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
clusters.tail()
```

Result:

```
0                  lat        lon
1587  37.921659  22...
1                  lat        lon
1658  37.933609  23...
2                  lat        lon
1607  37.966766  23...
3                  lat        lon
1586  38.149019  22...
4                  lat        lon
1584  38.374766  21...
                       
133              lat        lon
662  50.37369  18.889205
134               lat        lon
561  50.448704  19.0...
135               lat        lon
661  50.462271  19.0...
136               lat        lon
559  50.489304  19.0...
137             lat       lon
1  51.474005 -0.450999
```

Data Source:

https://github.com/gboeing/2014-summer-travels/tree/master/data

Relevant Resources:

https://github.com/gboeing/urban-data-science/blob/2017/15-Spatial-Cluster-Analysis/cluster-analysis.ipynb

https://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/

Answer (score 0):

During cluster assignment, one can also add to the distance a 'frequency penalty'. This is described in "Frequency Sensitive Competitive Learning for
Balanced Clustering on High-dimensional Hyperspheres - Arindam Banerjee and Joydeep Ghosh - IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks"

http://www.ideal.ece.utexas.edu/papers/arindam04tnn.pdf

They also have an online/streaming version.